# Merge JSON Array Without Overwriting Key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a retrieved JSON array as such from couchdb :

```
array(15) {
  ["_id"]=>
  string(15) "Axt"
  ["_rev"]=>
  string(34) "bd5137cbb8004e1a"
  ["api_rev"]=>
  string(3) "1.0"

  ["links"]=>
  array(1) {
    [3]=>
    array(5) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(8) "Assom"
      ["attribute"]=>
      string(0) "kkk"
    }
  }
```

Now i have to update this document by adding another array in "links" :

the array i have e.g $updatearr is :

```
["links"]=>
  array(1) {
    [3]=>
    array(5) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(8) "Mooa"
      ["attribute"]=>
      string(0) "okk"
    }
  }
```

When i try to merge by doing an array_merge, the new update overwrites the old "links". What i actually want if for there to be a new links type and attribute added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$array['links'][] = $updatearr['links'][0];
```

If there are more entries in $updatearr and you want to add them all, you can iterate over them and add all like above:

```
foreach ($updatearr['links'] as $link) {
  $array['links'][] = $link;
}
```

If there are more sub-arrays you want to merge, you better use array_merge but on subarrays:

```
$array['links'] = array_merge($array['links'], $updatearr['links']);
$array['locations'] = array_merge($array['locations'], $updatearr['locations']);
```

Comment: Thanks ! Mark as answer in 5 minutes

Comment: what if i have "links" then something else like "location"  and i want to do the same ? I dont want to create 2 foreach loops.

Comment: since the number of links & locations may differ in $updatearr, you have to create another loop. But that might not look good in your code. I think you better use array_merge on sub arrays. Let me update my answer accordingly..